# Which statistical parameter can be used to indicate how variable two signals are?

Tags: time-series, python, standard-deviation, nonparametric

Apart from approaches like Fourier transformation, Power spectrum or wavelets etc:

Which statistical parameter / value can I use to distinguish the two signals below?

Both have practically the same standard deviation, but the amount of changes per time unit are very different... .

[image: two signals with different frequencies and standard deviation shown]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)
i = 20000
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, i)
y1x = np.cos(x)+(np.random.rand(i) * .01 - .005)
y5x = np.cos(5 * x)+(np.random.rand(i) * .01 - .005)
plt.plot(x, y1x, '.',label='std:' + str(y1x.std()))
plt.plot(x, y5x, '.',label='std:' + str(y5x.std()))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```